# How to make views resized/panned when softkeyboard pop-on?

Tags: android

I have the following problem: I have an activity with a EditText on top and a toolbar on the bottom. When I select the EditText, the softkeyboard pops-on and hides the toolbar - but I want the EditText to be resized or panned, so I can see the toolbar while using the softkeyboard.
I've read the following article:
http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/on-screen-inputs.html
and set the attribute windowSoftInputMode:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

it just doesn't work. Then I also tried to set it to "adjustPan" - it doesn't work either. Here is the full layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/widget28"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#eceef2"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/my_border2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
     >  

         <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ibtnCancel"
                android:layout_width="42px"
                android:layout_height="44px"    
                android:src="@drawable/ico_reload"
                android:background="@drawable/buttonhighlight"              
                >
        </ImageButton>  
        <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/imvLogo"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="44px" 
              android:src="@drawable/stub"    
              android:scaleType="fitCenter"
              android:background="@drawable/my_border"
              />
        <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ibtnOK"
                android:layout_width="42px"
                android:layout_height="44px"    
                android:src="@drawable/ico_reload"
                android:background="@drawable/buttonhighlight"              
                >
        </ImageButton>                    

     </LinearLayout>

     <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/my_border2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
     >          
            <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etComment"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="top"           
            android:hint="Bạn đang nghĩ gì?"            
            android:textSize="18sp"             
            >
            </EditText> 
            <GridView android:id="@+id/gvEmoIcons"          
                android:background="#88000000"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:numColumns="auto_fit"
                android:verticalSpacing="10dp" 
                android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
                android:columnWidth="54dp" 
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth">
            </GridView>
     </FrameLayout>

     <!--  Emo icons bar -->
     <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llIconsBar" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"        
     >
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ibOpenSmileys" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/smile_smile"                     
        />          
     </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I've search for hours for this problem but haven't found the solution yet ! I appreciate your help.

Thanks,
Son